# Mongodb design for realtime aggregation & storage?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I want to store million of blogs & news articles to a mongodb server.

These articles will have some fields which I can use for aggregation such as: category, author, location,  domain, etc. I can store these articles in a mongo database but then those articles also have fields like text, summary which contain quite a lot of data and possibly make a document quite large (still < 16mb)

My question is when mongodb runs aggregation, does it read the whole document into memory and do the aggregation from there? Apparently, all the data from disk cannot fit into memory. Does the size of document affect the aggregation performance?

What is the good design/alternative for storage & "REALTIME" aggregation?

I don't want to use batch process like Hadoop for my project because Realtime aggregation is a must. I've seen a setup of 2 mongo dbs, 1 for storage which stores the original document, the other just store fields for aggregation in a star schema but I don't really like this approach because it would require to maintain the 2 versions of a document in 2 places.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a little ["too broad"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) a subject to be asking in this way. Try to narrow down to something specific or possibly break this into one part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is when mongodb runs aggregation, does it read the whole document into memory and do the aggregation from there?

No, since recent versions there has been a change in how projection works and now it is able to use covered queries or, rather, partial loading: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization

> The optimization phase applies the projection to the head of the pipeline such that only the _id and the amount fields return in the resulting documents from the $match stage as well.

So you can load bits of the document without worrying about loading the entire text content etc as well.

> Does the size of document affect the aggregation performance?

It effects any operation. Bigger the document the more IO is required to load it, even if the allocation is contiguous on the hard drive.

It can also effect, as you noted, memory usage. Your working set could find problems with larger documents and you could face page thrashing.

> What is the good design/alternative for storage & "REALTIME" aggregation?

Pre-aggregation with incremental map reduce is a good choice: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/ I personally use it far more than the aggregation framework, with much greater success.

> I don't want to use batch process like Hadoop for my project because Realtime aggregation is a must.

"Realtime"? What exactly is "realtime"? Is it on the spot with the user waiting while your server crunches the data for about 30 mins or is it the users data being delayed by 2 minutes and the user not waiting at all for page load times etc?

If you need high granularity then you can make the wait closer to 5 seconds between updates.

Realtime is not always on the spot processing, just look to many other sites on this front.

Comment: Thank @Sammaye for your answer. When I say realtime, I meant data should be able to read/aggregate right after it's inserted. And user should wait an appropriate time like 30s for the aggregation result to return. The aggregation process will not happen on the entire data set, but It will be relevant to a specific user by userId or something. An example could be building a chart of news articles from top 10 domains of last month for customer A. That's why I said Hadoop is not an ideal choice for my usecase.

Comment: @VanThoaiNguyen yeah with that added I would first see if aggregation is not too slow, if it is then I would move to pre-aggregated

Comment: Unfortunately, pre-aggregated might not be helpful for my case because I store duplicated documents which relevant to different users. By that, A user may rate, change, delete their news item in their way. There would be many combination of aggregations and filters so pre-aggreated cannot fit in.

Comment: @VanThoaiNguyen Hmm I would have to know the entire complexity of your scenario to advise on that but I have used pre-aggregation successfully for user generated content before, most commonly video statistics. It might be useful for small, heavy things you have lieing around, might even be appropiate to first form your data for aggregation framework

Comment: @VanThoaiNguyen, Did you find a proper a solution to avoid pre-aggregation ?  or direct aggreation on the data worked well? what is max documents per user and how many attributes per document and overall documents ?  I am also looking for similar direct so your answer would help many ppl here in forum

Comment: Hi @kcoder it's been 6 years, i'm no longer with that company. But this is the solution we had "at that time"

- We stored the fields of the document that required only for aggregation to a database
- We index the document to SOLR for full text search. Should have used ES :)
- We store the full document in a separated mongo db and used as key/lookup 


It run pretty well and performance is good. Now look back I'd try to store 1 weeks data to a separated db, 1m data to a separated db and 6m data in a separated db. Plus mongo now has WiredTiger Storage Engine it optimized storage verygood